# Where to get the base URL for rest service?

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I'm learning REST connector in data factory , I'm trying to create a linked services with REST, but it needs to provide base URL ,I wonder where I can get this.

Comment: You can get a base URL from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use many programe languages to build a REST Service. When you have permission to access this api, it will return a json object or json object array.
For example, using [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) to build a RESTful Web Service. In this case, `http://localhost:8080/` is your base url. If your domain is `localhost`, you need to use [self-hosted-integration-runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to connect to your local server.